# Fix the Header at Hop when scrill, footer at the Bottom

Tags: html, css

i am new to css.

How can i show footer at complete bottom of the page

my problem in this page : `http://techdefeat.com/index.php`

```
.technology {
    min-height: 203em;
}

.foot-nav {    background: #fa4b2a;}
```

in css this the only footer i have.

Please give some easy references, Thanks for Help.

Comment: Please share your code, so we can help with your problem :)

Comment: can you able to see the page source.?

Comment: Yes, but it makes it way more easier for us to help you, if you share the relevant code for you problem, instead of just "Can't you just see the page source". And what have you tried to do so far?

Comment: Hmm. True, give me a sec.

Comment: can you share the code?

Comment: @sankar can you please check above code please

Answer (score 0, accepted):

here is my solution for header.

**css**

```
.head-bottom {
    background: #fa4b2a;
    position:fixed;
    width:100%;
    z-index:100;
}

.tech-no {
    /* position: absolute; */
    / top: -33px; /
}
```

**JS**

```
$(window).scroll(function(e){ 
  var $el = $('.head-bottom'); 
  var isPositionFixed = ($el.css('position') == 'fixed');
  if ($(this).scrollTop() > 200 && !isPositionFixed){ 
    $('.head-bottom').css({'position': 'fixed', 'top': '0px'}); 
  }
  if ($(this).scrollTop() < 200 && isPositionFixed)
  {
    $('.head-bottom').css({'position': 'static', 'top': '0px'}); 
  } 
});
```

Looking for fix footer solution. thanks guys.

Answer (score 2):

For keep header on top when scroll and footer on bottom.

Set padding-bottom for `.technology` which is your main div. That should be equal to the height of your `footer`

**JS(jQuery):**

```
$(function(){
  $(window).scroll(function(){
    var headTop = $('.header-top').height();
    if($(this).scrollTop()>=headTop){
       $('.head-bottom').addClass('head-top');
    else
       $('.head-bottom').removeClass('head-top');
    }
  });
});
```

**CSS:**

```
.head-top{
    position: fixed;
    width: 100%;
    z-index: 999;
}

.technology{
  overflow:hidden;
  padding-bottom: 180px; // must be same height as the footer
}
.foot-nav {
  position: relative;
  margin-top: -180px;
  height: 180px;
  clear:both;
}
```

Comment: i found solution for Header Shankat, waiting for footer Solution.

Comment: Can you please remove `overflow:auto;` and provide some other solution. i don't want auto flow. i want to show footer at the dead end

Answer (score 1):

For the fixed header you can give both header these styles:

CSS:

```
.header {
    position: fixed;
    width: 100%;
    z-index: 1;
}
```

I can't see your footer at the moment?

Comment: `.foot-nav {    background: #fa4b2a;}` in css this the only footer i have.

Comment: please add a footer tag around that foot-nav

Comment: i added the above code to div, but the div is not coming at the top when scrolling.

Comment: It's because you only gave it to the class head-bottom. That's not what I wrote. Look at my answer and see where the code should go.

Comment: yes true, but can we move `head-bottom` top when we scroll.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/117329/discussion-between-developer-and-rasmusglenvig).